# AWS ec2 instance java EE web app deployment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ant, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

This would be a opinion based question. I would like to know the community opinion on the following.

I have a JAVA EE web application, which is using ANT as build tool. Now I have to deploy this application to multiple ec2 instances. What would be the best and most efficient way to do this.

I am using chef to fire up the instances and then installing custom jboss from a private repository.

Answer (score 0):

chef is generally used for setting up of infrastructure, and deployment activities should'nt be managed by that.

i prefer writing the scripts which actually does the deployment activities to the range of servers, or if having a CI for code, use CI for deployment as well.